# jquery get element replaced by text

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
 jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".wijstoe").change(function(){
            var id = $(this).children('#test').map(function() {
             return $(this).text();
            }).get();
            var mw = $("option").val();
            var opg = "Opgeslagen !";
            $("#loading").css("display","block");
            $.post("wijstoe.php",
                {mw:mw, id:id},
                function(data,status)
                {       
                    $("#loading").css("display","none");
                    $(this).children('#tester').html(opg);                                          
                });
        });
    });
```

HTML / PHP :

```
                        echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
                        echo "<td id='test1'>";
                        echo "<div class='wijstoe'>";
                        echo "<div id='test' style='display:none;'>".$row[0]."</div>";
                        echo "<form><select>";
                        if($_SESSION['uname'] == 'admin') {
                            $querya="select uname from users";
                            $resulta = mysql_query($querya);
                            while ($rowa = mysql_fetch_row($resulta)) {
                            echo "<option>".$rowa[0]."</option>";
                                    }
                        echo "</select></form>";
                        echo "<div id='tester'>DIDI</div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</td>";
                        }
```

This does not get the text from id tester (DIDI) replaced by the text opgeslagen.

When I don't use $(this) it works but then it works for every div with id tester, i just want this specific div to have the text replaced.

So this works :

```
  $(this).children('#tester').html(opg);
```

This does not work :

```
  $('#tester').html(opg);
```

Comment: are there multiple elements with the same id `tester`

Comment: Good point but no there are no multiple double elements.

Comment: if you execute `$('[id=tester]').length` in the browser console what is returned

Comment: >>> $('[id=tester]').length
432

Comment: That is the output of console.

Comment: that is the problem... where are 432 elements whose id is `tester`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $.post("wijstoe.php",
            {mw:mw, id:id},
            function(data,status)
            {       
                $("#loading").css("display","none");
                $(this).children('#tester').html(opg);                                          
            });
```

The $(this) at the location listed will be the POST method.

Having multiple elements with the same ID is not a good practice.  Change to a class when using on multiple elements.

```
var tester = $(this).find('.tester');

$.post("wijstoe.php",
     {mw:mw, id:id},
     function(data,status)
     {       
         $("#loading").css("display","none");
         $(tester).html(opg);                                          
     });
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked great !

I knew I should use id for unique names and class for multiple occurs, thanks for reminding me !

Now that we have a solution could you possibly explain me why your answers works and the answer above does not work ?!

WORKS :

var tester = $(this).find('.tester');
$(tester).html(opg);                                          

DOES NOT WORK :

$(this).find('#tester').html(opg);    

Both answers seem to be almost the same.
Is it because you set the var tester before $.post ($(this) will be the post method if we use it after $.post)

Comment: The difference is the # and .  . is CSS notation for a Class, and # is CSS notation for an Id

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(this).find('#tester').html(opg);
```